# sizeof inferring type long unsigned int instead of int in C

Tags: c, types, enums, integer

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum weekDays {
  Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday
};

int main()
{
  const enum weekDays today = Wednesday;

  printf("Size of today is %d", sizeof(today));

  return 0;
}
```

But im trying to compile using `gcc <filename> -o <output_name>` I get the following error:

```
enum.c: In function 'main':
enum.c:36:18: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long unsigned int' [-Wformat=]
   36 |   printf("Day %d", sizeof(today));
      |               ~^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                |   |
      |                int long unsigned int
      |               %ld
```

Like the return type of `sizeof` is a long unsigned int instead of an integer

Also, i saw a few C tutorials an the code i have is working fine in those videos. I.E:

[image]

Comment: Demo on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/rsoGjPYqj

Comment: Stop using that tutorial; it is bad. Using `%d` for a `sizeof` result is an elementary error that should not be in a tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) operator evaluates to a value of type `size_t`, not `int`.

The line

```
printf("Size of today is %d", sizeof(today));
```

will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because the `%d` conversion format specifier requires an argument of type `int`, but you are instead passing an argument of type `size_t` (which happens to be equivalent to `long unsigned int` on your platform).

That is why you are getting a warning message from the compiler.

The correct conversion format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu` instead of `%d`:

```
printf( "Size of today is %zu.\n", sizeof today );
```

See the documentation for [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for further information.